# Javascript not working, says class is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I'm trying to work with Ultra Cart and its giving me a huge headache. I'm using Moo tools also, and it seems that the pages are not connecting to j query. I referenced it properly but its not working. I'm new to JavaScript, so any help would be lovely. Is there something else that I need to add to use classes?

```
var Checkout = new Class({

var UltraCart = new Class({

MooTools.More={
```

The debugger says it something wrong with the first line in each script.

**Here's some links to the script online:**

view-source:http://www.wclarkpublishing.com/checkout

https://www.wclarkpublishing.com/js/ultracart.js

https://www.wclarkpublishing.com/js/checkout.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are loading MooTools after loading the ultracart.js file.

Load the javascript files in this order:

- mootools-core.js
- mootools-more.js
- ultracart.js
- checkout.js
- other js files

Your also loading jquery, which I think you are not using yet, so you could ditch that extra dependency.

Comment: Thank you! Putting them in the correct order has gotten it to work! Just a question, so I shouldn't reference jquery at all? I don't need it for my scripts?

Comment: As far as I could see you did not need it yes.